# How does a nonnegative matrix (with spectral radius $\rho(A) \geq 1$) change the magnitude of the L1 norm of a vector?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-decomposition, sequence-of-function, unitary-matrices

I have a square matrix $A(p)$ where all of its elements are positive but its spectral radius $\rho(A(p)) \geq 1$. I do not know the exact values of $A(p)$ since it depends the parameter $p$, but I know the formulas for every element of $A(p)$. I have a vector $x(p)$ which depends on $p$ and all of its elements are positive.

I want to study what happens for some limited integer $1\leq k < \infty$, how large $\Vert A^k x\Vert_1$ will become compared with $\Vert x\Vert_1$? Actually, we can form a finite sequence $\{x, Ax, A^2x, \cdots, A^k x\}$, and we know $b + e^T \sum\limits_{i=0}^k A^ix = 1$ where $e \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a all-one vector and $0<b<\infty$.

Comment: What does this have to do with algebraic geometry? Separately, it looks like you may have left a formula out of your final sentence.

Comment: Thanks. reedit. because $k$ is a parameter and we will get a sequence $\{x, Ax, A^2,x, \cdots, A^k x\}$ where $k$ is limited.

Comment: Your statement about SVD is not correct: if $A = USV^T$, we do not necessarily have $A^k = US^k V^T$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct since $A$ is not symmetric. I will correct it. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the power method and Perron Frobenius theorem if you have not already.